# Java fileReader - reading an int after String

Tags: java, oop, filereader

Hi I am creating a method to read data from a file (see format below) which has a name separated by ',' are 3 integers.

When the method is called the name is outputted fine but once I add an integer after it, it produces error - java.util.NoSuchElementException

Could someone tell me where i'm going wrong. Thanks.

UPDATE 
Thanks for below posts, problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use Scanner

```
while(in.hasNext()) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(in.nextLine());
        sc.useDelimiter(",");
        String name = sc.next();
        int DD = sc.nextInt();
        int MM = sc.nextInt();
        int YYYY = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println(name + DD + MM + YYYY);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `String name = in.nextLine();`, it will load complete line that is "name,5,6,1970", and thus again calling `int DD = in.nextInt();`will find nothing, and will throw exception

So try instead this:

```
public void readFile() {
        while(in.hasNext()) {
            String line = in.nextLine();
            String[] values = line.split(",");
            String name = values[0];
            int DD =  Integer.parseInt(values[1]);
            int MM =  Integer.parseInt(values[2]);
            int YYYY =  Integer.parseInt(values[3]);

            System.out.println(name + DD + MM + YYYY);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
String line = "name,5,6,1970"; //the whole line
String[] parts = line.split(",");
String name = parts[0]; //name
int DD = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]); //5
int MM = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]); //6
int YYYY = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]); //1970
```